# Как убрать символы и вывести в новый txt-файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть файл, в котором много IP-адресов. Пример:

```
[{'ip': '111.111.111.11'}, {'ip': '222.22.2.222'}]
```

Как мне убрать символы `[{':,}]` и сделать запись в новый файл `.txt` столбиком?

Comment: покажите пожалуйста результат, который вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) для парсинга этого выражения в объект `Python`.

***Пример:***

```py
from ast import literal_eval

with open('input.txt') as inp:
    s = inp.read()

li = literal_eval(s)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    for ip in li:
        out.write(ip['ip'] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот формат называется [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

В Вашем случае файл представляет собой список объектов.

Загрузить его в переменную можно использовав `json.loads`

```py
import json

with open('input.file') as f_ip:
  ip_json = f_ip.read()
  ip_list = json.loads(ip_json)
```

Далее работаем с полученным списком `ip_list`, выделяя нужные поля

```py
with open('result.file', 'w') as f_result:
  for ip in ip_list:
    print(ip['ip'], file=f_result)
```

Comment: Это не `JSON`. Символ `'` не является допустимым строковым литералом по спецификации. Хоть большинство парсеров и допускают его.